# accessing scope data outside ng-view in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have a SPA and the body of the index.html is something like below:

```
 <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div data-ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>
      <div data-ng-view=""></div>
     <div data-ng-include src="'partials/footer.html'"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 </body>
```

The header partials has many links which are mapped to controllers and the ng-view is populated with the corresponding partial file. Now I have to display the logged in username in the header.html file but I am not able to access the scope data inside the header.html file. I am populating the username inside all the controllers and putting the same inside the scope.

Please let me know how to access the scope data inside the header.html so that I can display the username.

Code snipper inside the controller:

```
controllers.BagsCtrl= function($scope,  $location, $route){
console.log('Inside the leather bags controller..');
    $scope.username = 'Pradeep';
}
```

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a controller that wraps all your application (on `<div id="wrapper">` for example) and declare the username on its `$scope` or put your username on the `$rootScope` and use it directly in your templates.

The first way seems to be cleaner.